# Trans Replication and Always On Listener Group Name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, transactional-replication

We have currently (SQL Server 2012 STD) which is continuously replicating from 8 different database server for reporting purpose to server which is on SQL 2008R2. We would like to create an Always On Availability group for this reporting database so we can have multiple replicas. We have 8 database servers as our 2000 stores are round robin on these 8 server. To get data into one reporting database with multiple replica, we would like to do the following:

1. Create Transactional Replication from this 8 database server (i.e.SQL Server 2012) to 1 SQL Server 2012 database server which would be the Primary Replica for AOG
2. Create multiple replicas from this Primary using normal AOG system

Is there any way to make the Primary Replica as a Subscriber coming 8 database servers?
I tried to create the AOG Listener group and tried to use that name while adding Subscriber to replication, but it says it needs a Server Name.
Can somebody please help me on this?

Thank you,
HP